# How should I format my string to pass it to my database via TIBCO BW6?

Tags: datetime, jdbc, tibco, tibco-business-works

I'm new to TIBCO BW6. This is my scenario. I have a .csv file, and one of my columns is a string in this format: '31/08/2021 15:18:00'

I created a process that reads my file and inserts a new row into my database. I have a problem with the date.

In my palette JDBC Update, the date is a timestamp. When I match the input, the right pattern for matching my string in datetime is pattern yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of thing the best solution is generally to use the SQL database formatting functions in your SQL query.

Something like this (for ORACLE) :

```
insert into table_name 
(my_date_field)
values (TO_DATE('2022/01/23 11:25:44', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

In BusinessWorks the query would look like this and you would have to map the value of the field corresponding to the '?' with your actual timestamp :

```
insert into table_name 
(my_date_field)
values (TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: thanks, I still found the solution to the problem. It was enough to use this solution tib:parse-dateTime("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",$Data/tns3:data_lettura)

Comment: Yes this is another possible approach (do the formatting in BusinessWorks)